# What is an early register in ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture

I was working on exception return and mode switches in armv7. I came across the RFE and SRS instructions. I read through them and stumbled across this line 
"In all cases the base register is an Early register, and requires an extra cycle of result latency to provide its value." I find this strange to mention specifically since this would be the case with any register I think.

This is the first time I am coming across anything like this and I checked in the architecture reference manual, I couldn't find any description about an "Early Register". I would like to know what are they and how they are classified ?

Comment: Anything talking about cycles is a microarchitectural detail of a specific pipeline design, so it would help to have a bit more context of what reference you're quoting and what specific CPU we're talking about here - as you've found, this is outside the scope of the architecture itself.

Comment: Ah, on further inspection it appears the reference to ARMv7 is misleading as this comes from the timing section of one of the ARM11 TRMs, [which already explicitly defines the term](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0333h/Chdibfgi.html)...

Comment: The RFE and SRS instructions are present in the armv7 architecture manual also. During literature survey about those instructions  I cam across this "Early register concept". The link above gives a pretty complex definition of early register  "The specified registers are required at the start of the Sh, MAC1, and ADD stage. Add one cycle to the result latency of the instruction producing this register for interlock calculations." May be I need to look more in to the pipelining stages in ARM to grasp it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example code:

```
LDR R3, [R0,#0x04]
CMP R3, R2
```

now in this case as **load instruction** takes some clock cycles to process and the value is not immediately available to **compare instruction**. In this case the core will stall until the +k cycles have elapsed since we are using R3 **earlier** before the result is actually written to it.